# sort array by frequency - there is a better solution?

Tags: arrays, sorting

i'm looking for algorithm that can implement this problem:
input: array of strings
output: the strings ordered by:

a) frequency (main sort)
b) a-z

so if the input is:

"foo","cat","foo","cool","cat","goo","cool"

output should be:

"cat","cat","cool","cool","foo","foo","goo"

i can put everything in hashmap string->int(freq).

then sort the map it by key,value.

anyway complexity of (O(n*log(n)).

can it be done better?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to solve this in a specific language? If not,

Using `lodash` you can solve like this:

```
_.join(_.sortBy(_.groupBy(["foo","cat","foo","cool","cat","goo","cool"])))
```

This will give the output as: `cat,cat,cool,cool,foo,foo,goo`

Comment: hi. i don't care for a language. i just want to know if it is can be done better from performance perspective